# google is indexing Apache Test page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, google-index

Let's say I have a website, `example.com`. But the contents for this website is on another domain, say `test.com/test` and redirections are happening using `htaccess` files.

I have set up `301 redirection` for redirecting from `test.com/test` to `example.com`. The issue is when I search for `example.com`, I am getting an Apache Test page, and when I queried like site: `example.com` for getting the Google crawled page, I am getting a `403 Forbidden` error.

How can I fix this problem? The site is working fine. This site is also indexing correctly in other search engines (namely Yahoo and Bing).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to block Google from indexing that page:

```
User-Agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /
```

Or for all the search engines, this way:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Be informed that it will skip the entire domain. If it has a particular page name, say `index.htm`, you can use that this way:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /index.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Can the test page still be reached? Do you get the test page if you click the link in Google?

If so, you must still change that url so it redirects.

If not, Google probably has indexed it before you made the redirect. Just wait a while until Google re-indexes your site. This may take from hours to several days or weeks, depending on the amount of traffic to your site, ranking, frequency of previous updates, moon position, wind speed, and all kinds of other variables that Google uses for their algorithm. :-/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this site is live for last 2 year. I am getting this Apache test only when i searched on Google. Otherwise it is working fine.

Comment: That's really odd. It looks like the domain is returning the test page when I click the link from Google, but the actual page when I type the url or refresh the page. Seems like the domain is using the referrer to display another page. If Google gets the test page when crawling, instead of the 403, that may explain why the pages still exist in the search results.